# Full calendar not showing events generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

My events are not getting displayed on fullcalendar. I am fetching the list of events from the backend server using nodejs. the events are getting generated dynamically. I am able to get the events in array but t he events are not showing on the calendar. Any help would be appreciated

```
function searchappointmentssss(forappdate) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/searchappointment',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      date: forappdate
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var aaaaaaa = [];
      data.forEach(function(dataa) {
        var ddddddd = dataa.date.split("T");
        var appppppp = {};
        appppppp.title = dataa.patientname + "\n" + dataa.purposeofvisit;
        appppppp.description = dataa.purposeofvisit;
        appppppp.start = ddddddd[0] + " " + dataa.time;
        appppppp.end = ddddddd[0] + " " + dataa.endtime;
        appppppp.id = dataa.appointmentid;
        appppppp.visstatus = dataa.status;
        appppppp.gicid = dataa.gic;
        aaaaaaa.push(appppppp);
      });

      console.log(aaaaaaa);
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: "agendaDay",
        defaultDate: "2018-10-26",
        events: aaaaaaa,

        eventTextColor: '#ffffff',
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: ''

        },
        viewRender: function(view, element) {
          var newddddddd = moment($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate')).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
          searchappointmentssss(newddddddd);
          $("#dateselectedforapp").val(newddddddd + "T00:00");
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          $("#exampleModal2").modal('toggle');
          $("#message-textm4").val(calEvent.id);
          $("#message-textm444").val(calEvent.gicid);
          $("#message-textm").val(calEvent.description);
          $("#message-textm6").val(calEvent.visstatus);
          $("#message-textm99").val(moment(calEvent.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
          $("#message-textm2").val(moment(calEvent.start).format("hh:mm"));
          $("#message-textm3").val(moment(calEvent.end).format("hh:mm"));

          // change the border color just for fun
          $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

        }
      });

      //document.execCommand("InsertImage", false, "upload/"+data);
      //alert(data);
      //$("#progressbar").hide();
      //location.reload();
      //$("#article").load("submitArticle.php");
      //window.location.href = window.location.href;
    },
    error: function() {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Ps: Just putting this text cos stackoverflow was saying you question contains only code. this is not relevant :P

Comment: Can you please show us the output of doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(aaaaaaa));` (run it just before the `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({` line, please). The most likely thing in this type of circumstance is an issue with the dates.

Comment: Also looking at your code, I think maybe you are creating an infinite loop - if you call searchAppointments, it then creates the calendar. The first time you create the calender, it will run "viewRender"...this will then call searchAppointments, which will create a new calendar, which will then call viewRender, which will then call searchAppointments...and so on round and round you will go. A better way is to create the calendar once, and then use [this pattern](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) to allow fullCalendar to make the AJAX request whenever it's required.